# Visual Studio Build Error Message. What does it mean?

Tags: message

[image]

I've got these error messages and i don't know, what does it meant. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear you are not linking against the library/object that contains `NavstreetsDataSource`. Include it in your linker options or maybe it's excluded from your build.